# Buscar datos en sql y rellenar imputs con los valores recibidos con ajax y php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

estoy tratando de buscar unos valores en una tabla SQl a condicion del valor de un textbox, pero no recibo nada, no se donde puede estar el problema.

hasta ahora tengo este codigo:

```
$(document).on('change', '#referencias', function(){
    
    $('#refabuscar').val($("#referencias").val());
    $("#datos").show(); 
        
});
$(document).on('change', '#refabuscar', function(){
    var refabuscar = $("#refabuscar").val()
    
      $.ajax({
        url:"buscar.php",
        method:"POST",
        data:{referencia:refabuscar, action:'busca'},
        dataType:'JSON',
        success:function(data)
        {
              
            $('#tamano').val(data.Tamano);
            $('#color').val(data.Color);
            $('#origen').val(data.Origen);
            
            

        }
    })
});
```

y en el archivo Buscar

```
    if($_POST["action"] == 'busca')
{
    $conexion->query = "
    SELECT * FROM referencias 
    WHERE Referencia = '".$_POST["referencia"]."'
    ";

    $result = $conexion->get_result();

    $data = array();

    foreach($result as $row)
    {
        $data['Tamano'] = $row['Tamano'];
        $data['Color'] = $row['Color'];
        $data['Origen'] = $row['Origen'];
        
    }

    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

alguien sabria decirme donde esta el problema?

puse varios alerts para probar y efectivamente si que muestra el valor que quiero enviar, o la variable basicamente, pero no se si el problema puede estar en el php, el result conexion funciona bien, porque le uso en el mismo codigo para otras cosas sin problemas.

gracias

Comment: ¿El buscador debe encontrar solo una fila que coincida? ¿Siempre se debe teclear la referencia completa? ¿Si ejecutas la consulta en PhpMyAdmin devuelve el resultado esperado?

Comment: Buenas ya conseguí que funcionase, al final era un tema de id, que había 2 repetidos.